# Accessing dictionary keys&values via list of keys and values

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration

This is going to be a very embarrassing first post from me - just coming back to coding in Python after learning basics ~6 months ago and not using it since then.

I am coding a Blackjack game in object oriented approach, and defined a Deck object as shown below:

```
class Deck(object):
    suits = ["spades", "clubs", "diamonds", "hearts"]
    ranks = ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"]

def __init__(self):
    self.spades = {"2": 0, "3": 0, "4": 0, "5": 0, "6": 0, "7": 0, "8": 0, "9": 0, "10": 0, "Jack": 0, "Queen": 0, "King": 0, "Ace": 0}
    self.clubs = {"2": 0, "3": 0, "4": 0, "5": 0, "6": 0, "7": 0, "8": 0, "9": 0, "10": 0, "Jack": 0, "Queen": 0, "King": 0, "Ace": 0}
    self.diamonds = {"2": 0, "3": 0, "4": 0, "5": 0, "6": 0, "7": 0, "8": 0, "9": 0, "10": 0, "Jack": 0, "Queen": 0, "King": 0, "Ace": 0}
    self.hearts = {"2": 0, "3": 0, "4": 0, "5": 0, "6": 0, "7": 0, "8": 0, "9": 0, "10": 0, "Jack": 0, "Queen": 0, "King": 0, "Ace": 0}
```

Afterwards, I wanted to create a neat method which would initiate this deck by filling all 4 dictionaries holding count of ranks in each suit, by writing something like below (that's the reason for class attributes I defined above:

```
def initialize_deck(self):
    for suit in self.suits:
        for rank in self.ranks:
            self.suit[rank] = 1
```

The problem is, the code just does not do what I think it should be doing (as in e.g.: pulling first suit from self.suits list, using it as a name of the dictionary iterating over all its keys and setting their associated values to 1). Instead I just get an error "AttributeError: 'Deck' object has no attribute 'suit'".

What am I doing wrong in here? Is there a neat way of writing what I have in mind with 2 nested loops, instead of writing it like below?

```
def initialize_deck(self):
    for rank in self.ranks:
        self.spades[rank] = 1
    for rank in self.ranks:
        self.clubs[rank] = 1
    for rank in self.ranks:
        self.diamonds[rank] = 1
    for rank in self.ranks:
        self.hearts[rank] = 1
```

Thanks in advance for answers to what I know is probably a very basic problem.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getattr` function do get attribute from object

```
def initialize_deck(self):
    for suit in self.suits:
        suit_dict = getattr(self, suit)
        for rank in self.ranks:
            suit_dict[rank] = 1
```

Or you can do it using `setattr`

```
def initialize_deck(self):
    rank_map = {key: 1 for key in self.ranks}
    for suit in self.suits:
        setattr(self, suit, rank_map.copy())
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this - the first solution worked like a wonder!

Comment: Just out of curiosity - why was my initial code not working? From the flow of the program it should have had both the name of the dictionary and the keyword to set to 1 by the time it was in the action space of the 2nd loop, yet it did not put it together... Even just a link to an article covering that topic would be appreciated.

Comment: @Greem666 The problem is that when you do your "self.suit" it refers to "suit" attribute of your object, while your variable "suit" links to some string. To get an attribute from the object by its name you should use the function "getattr". Not sure if there is a good article that covers this problem.